# c/c++: error of printing a double array returned by a function

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers, double

I got a problem with the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double* FillArray(void) 
{   
    double result[5]; 

    for (int i = 0; i<5;i++){
        result[i]=(double) i;

    }
    return result; // return the pointer
}

int main()
{   

    double * a = FillArray();
    for (int i = 0; i<5;i++){
        cout << a[i] << endl; // print out the array
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The outputs are strange:

```
0
3.47187e-236
8.89753e-308
8.8976e-308
3.90251e-236
```

Could you tell what wrong in my code? 
I tried to use a function to return an array, and print out it in the main().

Comment: The result array goes out of scope at the end of the FillArray() function.

Comment: Turn up the warning level on your compiler, it should have told you something was fishy about this code.

Comment: There's a huge problem with your title: "c/c++". Stick to one of both languages. Either leave C++ behind, or delve into the realm of `std::vector` and his useful companions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope)

Answer (score 4):

You are returning a pointer to a local variable, the array `result`. This is *undefined behaviour*. The variable ceases to exist when the function returns, so by the time you get to printing, you print garbage values.

If you really want to return an array, you can use an `std::array`:

```
typedef std::array<double, 5> DArray5;

DArray5 FillArray() 
{
    DArray5 result; 

    for (size_t i = 0; i < result.size(); ++i){
        result[i] = i;
    }
    return result;
}
```

**Edit** This is a C++ only answer. There is no C/C++ language.

Comment: For OP: if you don't know what undefined behaviour is, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior/4105123#4105123.

Comment: So, what is the reason for the down-vote? Is there anything wrong, misleading or controversial in this answer? If so, I would gladly think about making changes.

Comment: A couple of issues: 1) an array (or, arguably better, vector) exists only in C++ - not C.  2) I would discourage hard-coding "5" multiple times.  3) In the same vein, I would use container::begin() .. container::end() instead of (for (int i=0; i < 5; i++).  IMHO...

Comment: @paulsm4 fair enough, except that I wouldn't use the iterators because the index is needed. And I don't want to confuse OP with `std::iota` just yet, and I don't agree that `vector` is a better solution. OP has a fixed size array. As for C, I find that irrelevant here, since the question is tagged C++.

Comment: Thank you, but "std::array" can only be use in visual studio 2012.

Comment: @PengLi In general, you should specify special restrictions that prevent you from using the current C++ standard. But there are alternatives. There is `std::tr1::array` and `boost::array`. Then there are a whole bunch of standard library containers, such as `std::vector`.

Answer (score 2):

`result` is allocated in the stack. Try allocating it in the heap, like this:

```
double* result = new double[5];
```

Comment: Thank you, but I have to delete it after use.

Comment: You're welcome. In `main` you write `double* a = FillArray();`. So, I thought you wanted to use dynamically allocated data to begin with; I didn't want to change `FillArray`'s signature.

Answer (score 0):

The array called result get released. Try this code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void FillArray(double *result) 
{   
    for (int i = 0; i<5;i++){
        result[i]=(double) i;
    }
}

int main()
{   
    double result[5]; 
    FillArray(result);
    for (int i = 0; i<5;i++){
        cout << result[i] << endl; // print out the array
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is WRONG:

```
double* FillArray(void) 
{   
    // Result ONLY has scope INSIDE of the FillArray function
    double result[5]; 

    for (int i = 0; i<5;i++){
        result[i]=(double) i;

    }
    // Bad things will happen when the caller tries to use (now-invalid) "result"
    return result;
```

Here is one correct alternative:

```
#define ARRAY_SIZE 5

main ()
    double result[ARRAY_SIZE]; 
    FillArray (result, ARRAY_SIZE);
    for (int i = 0; i<ARRAY_SIZE;i++){
        cout << result[i] << endl; // print out the array
    }
    ...
void FillArray(double *array, int n) 
{   
    for (int i = 0; i<n;i++){
        array[i]=(double) i;
```

Comment: I would recommend *against* either code samples in any situation.